# Javascript Array: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Creating a JSON object is very straightforward.  Not sure where is the problem. 
Trying to create a JSON object like this:

```
var result = [
            {"member":"member1", "person":"person1"},
            {"member":"member2", "person":"person2"}
];
```

**Here is the code:**

```
$ = cheerio.load('<table><tbody><tr><td>message1</td><td>person1</td></tr><tr><td>message2</td><td>person2</td></tr><tr><td>message3</td><td>person3</td></tr></tbody></table>');
var result = {};
$('tr').each(function(i, row){
    result[i].message.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
    result[i].person.push($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
});
```

**Error:**
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`

Comment: You declare `var result = {};`, and then try to access keys (with `i`), but it has none...so `result[i]` will always be `undefined`. And `undefined` doesn't have a "message" property

Comment: `var result = {}` is an empty object.

Comment: apparently `result[0]` is undefined. (which is true if you are using the code in your question.)

Comment: @Ian Got it. Then how would I create desired array dynamically?

Comment: Something like `var results = [];`. Then inside the `each()` loop, do something like `results[i] = {}; results[i].message = "something"; results[i].person = "something else";`

Answer (score 1):

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

$ = cheerio.load('<table><tbody><tr><td>message1</td><td>person1</td></tr><tr><td>message2</td><td>person2</td></tr><tr><td>message3</td><td>person3</td></tr></tbody></table>');
var result = [];
$('tr').each(function(i, row){

    result[i] = {
        message: $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
        person: $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()
    };

});

console.log (result);
```

result:

```
[ { message: 'message1', person: 'person1' },
  { message: 'message2', person: 'person2' },
  { message: 'message3', person: 'person3' } ]
```

Comment: This is not a what I expect. Why is there `[]` around attribute values?

Comment: not sure why you need an array of message/person. you could also just do this: `result[i].message =  $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(); result[i].person  =  $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();` result: `[ { message: 'message1', person: 'person1' },
  { message: 'message2', person: 'person2' },
  { message: 'message3', person: 'person3' } ]`

Comment: If you run it you will see a different result.
`{ '0': { message: 'message1', person: 'person1' },
  '1': { message: 'message2', person: 'person2' },
  '2': { message: 'message3', person: 'person3' } }`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
var result = new Array();
$('tr').each(function(i, row){

    var ele = {
        message: $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
        person: $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()
    };
    console.log(ele);
    result.push(ele);
}); 

console.log(result);
```